# Printing to label printer using IP address

Tags: c#

I have a label printer on the network, and have the drivers installed on my pc. I'm printing to the printer using

```
printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Argox A-2240ME PPLB";
```

Is there a way to address the printer in this methd, but by IP address?

Comment: try to enumerate the printers on the network and get its properties to see its ip, this may help  http://tech.pro/tutorial/927/wpf-print-queues-and-capabilities

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to call it by IP. If the label printer ever changes from IP address, you'll have to rewrite your application instead of using DNS to resolve it.

Comment: Jonathan, in case of the these particular label printers, they have static ip, the problem is that I have more than one with same name!